# What percentage of the Death Star was habitable/habitated?

Tags: star-wars, death-star

I was wondering what percentage within the fully operational Death Star I had people actively living there, working there, etc. Perhaps everyone was near the surface and the inner parts were inhospitable all-machinery? Or no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All signs point to the '*city sprawl*' on the exterior of the station being the main place in which the station's population work and live, with the interior being largely focused on engines, weaponry, power generation, etc.

> **City Sprawl - Living Quarters**
>
> Living quarters aboard the Death Star ranged from spartan barracks for
> the crew to multi-room luxury apartments for the senior officers.
> Lower officers, such as lieutenants, shared their quarters with as
> many as three other officers of like rank. Higher officers received
> private quarters. The crew quarters bunked as many as 50 individuals
> in a room, but some crew members received preferential treatment.
> Combat pilots and highly-skilled technical crew received better living conditions than the average service tech or lab assistant.
>
> <sub><sup>***[Death Star Technical Companion](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Star_Technical_Companion)***</sup></sub>

[image]<sub><sup>[DS-1 Death Star Owner's Technical Manual](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Death_Star_Owner%27s_Technical_Manual)</sup></sub>

---

We know that the station has a width of 160 kilometres, meaning that the depth of the 'city sprawl' (based on our observation of the blueprint below) is about [160 metres](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/DS-1_Death_Star_Mobile_Battle_Station). Assuming 80% of *that* is freely usable as habitable space (e.g. minus the bit with the big death-spewing laser dish in the middle of it), that means that **the living area represents about 5% of the total interior volume of the Death Star.**

> [image]
>
> <sub><sup>*[Star Wars Blueprints: The Ultimate Collection](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_The_Ultimate_Collection)*</sup></sub>

Comment: Proving once again that writers have no sense of scale.  A single storey of habitation chambers over just 10% of the surface area yields over 2000m^2 per person assuming over 2 million inhabitants. :-P  And that's in 0.2% of the surface volume; use just 1% of just the surface and each person gets over 10000m^2 (**1 ha**) of personal space.  Bunking 4 lieutenants together is just not applying any thought.

Comment: @DavidW - Oh sure. The thing is vast and everyone could have their own town-sized bedroom without any problems, but you're not thinking like a military planner.

Comment: (Nothing I say here should detract from the fact this is a good answer, +1.)  But if I were thinking about it from a _military_ point of view, I wouldn't spread all the soft squishy bits in a thin layer on the outside either!  (I would make all the non-military parts of the outer 1km storage for bulk, inert, non-combat-critical supplies, like water and food.)

Comment: @davidw water and food aren’t combat critical? When you’ve just blown up the nearest planet?

Comment: One imagines that a lot of the crustal-habitation-zone is taken up by support-equipment for the hundreds or thousands of shield projectors, turbolaser emplacements, sensors, communications and auxiliary systems studding the surface. I imagine that if people live on the surface itself, they most likely live in discrete habitation-sectors when they're not bunking near their duty-stations.